# Explicit sort in Cartesian transformation in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cartesian

I am using Cartesian transformation in Spark Scala. If my input consists of 4 elements (could be numbers/characters/tuple) say

```
var myRDD=sc.parallelize(Array("e1","e2","e3","e4"))
```

myRDD.cartesian(myRDD) would yield all possible combination of pairs but not necessarily in order. What is a smart way to get those pairs in Order? i.e.

```
Array((e1,e1), (e1,e2), (e1,e3), (e1,e4), (e2,e1), (e2,e2), (e2,e3), (e2,e4), (e3,e1), (e3,e2), (e3,e3), (e3,e4), (e4,e1), (e4,e2), (e4,e3), (e4,e4))
```

Comment: What kind of order you need? And more important, why do you need this ordered?

Comment: I have a set of coordinates in (x,y,z), and I need to compute RMSD distance between them. I used Cartesian transformation to get coordinates pair ex. ((C1, C2), (C1,C3), ..). The order is important so I know which distance belong to which pair.

Comment: I think the best approach is to zip each point with the index, so you can identify them later, instead of sorting that will require you to collect all the data to the master. Think of this, the possible combinations will be huge!!! and they might not fit the memory!

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto - if the OP needs all the pairwise distances, then the combinations are already huge. Please explain how your proposal of zipping with the index delivers the OP's requirement..

Comment: @KentCarlevi. I don't get why you need the order. Why not transform your RDD of coord-pairs to ((C1,C2, RMSD), ...(Cx, Cy, RMSD)...)? Also, what will you do with the result? Presumably filter it in some way?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul The order is important because I want to create a nxn rmsd coordinatematrix for n coordinates.  If I transform my pairs to (Cx, Cy, RMSD), the index information is lost.

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is to be able to identify each point (so you can determine the pair of points and their `L2` distance), thus what you really require is to add an `id` to each entry in the `RDD` or `DataFrame`.

If you want to use an `RDD`, the approach I recommend is:

```
myRDD = sc.parallelize([(0, (0.0, 0.0)), (1, (2.0, 0.0)), 
                        (2, (-3.0, 2.0)), (3, (-6.0, -4.0))])

combinations = myRDD.cartesian(myRDD).coalesce(32)

distances = combinations\
    .filter(lambda (x, y): x[0] < y[0])\
    .map(lambda ((id1, (x1, y1)), (id2, (x2, y2))): (id1, id2, ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5))

distances.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `sorted` function? Seems to sort Tuples by its first member, then by second and so on:

```
scala> val a = Array((1, 1), (3, 3), (2, 2))
a: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (3,3), (2,2))

scala> a.sorted
res1: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (2,2), (3,3))

scala> val a = Array((1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3))
a: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (3,1), (2,3))

scala> a.sorted
res2: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (2,3), (3,1))

scala> val a = Array((1, 2), (3, 1), (1, 1))
a: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (3,1), (1,1))

scala> a.sorted
res3: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (1,2), (3,1))
```

Comment: The OP is using Spark (despite the Array in their example). RDDs don't have  `.sorted` (but they do have `.sortBy`  which will do the job. Expensively)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. If the sorting is expensive, I guess I can use List comprehension to get the pairs.

Comment: I think this approach is very inappropriate, for requiring you to collect the data in your master (if you work with a cluster), with the possible problems during the execution.

Comment: No, it doesn't require collection in the master? (if you use `RDD.sortBy`). The `Array` is just for illustration, the real case uses an RDD.