# Upper triangle of cartesian in spark for symmetric operations: `x*(x+1)//2` instead of `x**2`

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to compute pairwise symmetric scores for items of a list in Spark. I.e. `score(x[i],x[j]) = score(x[j], x[i])`. One solution is to use `x.cartesian(x)`. However it will perform `x**2` operations instead of minimal necessary `x*(x+1)//2`.

What is the most efficient remeady for this issue in Spark?

PS. In pure Python I would use iterator like:

```
class uptrsq_range(object):

    def __init__(self, n):

        self._n_ = n
        self._length = n*(n+1) // 2

    def __iter__(self):
        for ii in range(self._n_):
            for jj in range(ii+1):
                yield (ii,jj)

    def __len__(self):
        """
        recepe by sleblanc @ stackoverflow
        """
        "This method returns the total number of elements"
        if self._length:
            return self._length
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("Infinite sequence has no length")
            # or simply return None / 0 depending
            # on implementation

for i,j in uptrsq_range(len(x)):
    score(x[i], x[j])
```

Comment: If xs are to large to fit into memory of a single machine or cannot be easily computed from scratch the only option is something like this: `x.cartesian(x).filter(lambda x: x[0] < [1])`. Otherwise you can use `flatMap` or `mapPartitions`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you post it as an answer? The `filter` trick does make sense to me. Could you explain a bit more how you would go with two other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most universal approach is to follow `cartesian` with `filter`. For example:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(10))

pairs = rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter(lambda x: x[0] < x[1])
pairs.count()

## 45
```

If RDD is relatively small you can collect, broadcast and `flatMap`:

```
xs = sc.broadcast(rdd.collect())
pairs = rdd.flatMap(lambda y: [(x, y) for x in xs.value if x < y])
pairs.count()

## 45
```

This is particularly useful if data can be further filtered inside `flatMap` to reduce number of yielded values.

If data is too large to be collected / stored in memory but can be easily computed (like a range of numbers) or can be efficiently accessed from the worker (locally accessible database) you can `flatMap` as above or use `mapPartitions` for example like this:

```
def some_function(iter):
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    query = ...  

    for x in iter:
        # fetch some data from a database
        c.execute(query, (x, ))
        for y in c.fetchall():
            yield (x, y)

rdd.mapPartitions(some_function)
```

Comment: Too* large, i can't modify it because the modification is too short. And this question is somehow related to [Explicit sort in Cartesian transformation in Scala Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660998/explicit-sort-in-cartesian-transformation-in-scala-spark/33679034#33679034)